# ¿ Como mostrar y ordenar algunos campos en el checkout de WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, users-roles, checkout

EDITO LA PREGUNTA

Encontre más información buscando en otros sitios y encontre documentación [de "Business Bloomer"](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-custom-checkout-field-%20php/).

El ejemplo es similar a lo que yo tenia, pero lo cambie. En el se crea el nuevo campo, se muestra y posteriormente se guarda y se envian los datos de este campo en los email a los clientes.

Estes es el ejemplo:

```
/* mostramos el nuevo campo en la página checkout */
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'bbloomer_add_custom_checkout_field' );
  
function bbloomer_add_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) { 
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   $saved_license_no = $current_user->license_no;
   woocommerce_form_field( 'license_no', array(        
      'type' => 'text',        
      'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),        
      'label' => 'NIF/CIF',        
      'placeholder' => 'B12345678',        
      'required' => true,        
      'default' => $saved_license_no,        
   ), $checkout->get_value( 'license_no' ) ); 
}

/* asegurarnos de que el nuevo campo no esté vacío */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'bbloomer_validate_new_checkout_field' );
  
function bbloomer_validate_new_checkout_field() {    
   if ( ! $_POST['license_no'] ) {
      wc_add_notice( 'Por favor ingrese su número de NIF', 'error' );
   }
}

/* se guarda el nuevo campo  y se muestra en email, checkout, et */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'bbloomer_save_new_checkout_field' );
  
function bbloomer_save_new_checkout_field( $order_id ) { 
    if ( $_POST['license_no'] ) update_post_meta( $order_id, '_license_no', esc_attr( $_POST['license_no'] ) );
}
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_thankyou' );
   
function bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_thankyou( $order_id ) {    
   if ( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_license_no', true ) ) echo '<p><strong>NIF/CIF:</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order_id, '_license_no', true ) . '</p>';
}
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_order' );
   
function bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_order( $order ) {    
   $order_id = $order->get_id();
   if ( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_license_no', true ) ) echo '<p><strong>NIF/CIF:</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order_id, '_license_no', true ) . '</p>';
}
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_emails', 20, 4 );
  
function bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_license_no', true ) ) echo '<p><strong>NIF/CIF:</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_license_no', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Y en este mismo sito, [encontre la forma de reordenar](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-move-reorder-fields-checkout-page/) los campos con la siguiente función. Unicamente, no funciona ya que el nuevo campo que creamos en el código anterior `(license_no)` , quiero colocarlo debajo del campo `"Nombre de la empresa (opcional)"`

Unicamente se muestra el `input` , el `label` NIF/CIF no se muestra, y el placeholder tampoco se muestra. Se muestra unicamente el cajon del `input`.

¿ Que estoy haciendo mal en mi ejemplo ?
¿ Que debo corregir para que se muestre todo correctamente después de reordenar el nuevo campo creado ?

Vean la forma de hacerlo:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'bbloomer_reorder_checkout_fields' );
 
function bbloomer_reorder_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
 
   // default priorities:
   // 'first_name' - 10
   // 'last_name' - 20
   // 'company' - 30
   // 'country' - 40
   // 'address_1' - 50
   // 'address_2' - 60
   // 'city' - 70
   // 'state' - 80
   // 'postcode' - 90
 
  // e.g. move 'company' above 'first_name':
  // just assign priority less than 10
  $fields['license_no']['priority'] = 35;
 
  return $fields;
}
```